# How in Java to prevent constructor from throwing exception

Tags: java, exception

I have the following Trip class:

```
class Trip {
    final ArrayList<GpsPoint> gpsPoints;
    final String name;

    Trip(String name, ArrayList<GpsPoint> gpsPoints) throws SpecialException {
        if (gpsPoints.size() < 5) {
            throw SpecialException("not enough GPS points");
        }

        this.name = name;
        this.gpsPoints = gpsPoints;
    }
}
```

Now I want to return a **new** trip object as follows:

```
// method inside trip class
Trip makeTripWithNewName(String newName) {
    return new Trip(newName, this.gpsPoints);
}
```

But this method has to throw SpecialException, even if I am definitely sure exception will not occur (because when Trip object is already constructed and we only have to rename it, it will have at least 5 points).

How to avoid typing

```
Trip makeTripWithNewName(String newName) throws SpecialException {
    ...
}
```

?

Comment: You could make `SpecialException` inherit from [`RuntimeException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html). Then you don't need to write code to handle it (in cases where you are sure it will not be thrown).

Comment: If the gpsPoints will never reach below 5, then in which cases do you need an exception to be returned?

Comment: or just catch the SpecialException and rethrow it as a RuntimeException. But apart from that: Why does your rename method of Trip create and return a new Trip object? Shoudn't it rename the current Trip instead like the method name suggests? edit: `makeTripWithNewName` is a much clearer name. So ignore what i wrote earlier ;)

Comment: @ChrisGong, it can reach below 5 when I am trying to construct Trip from other sources. In the specific `rename` case it will not hit below 5 because a properly constructed trip will already have 5 points.

Comment: So when do you want `rename` to throw an exception if you know the gpsPoints won't ever cause an exception to be thrown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Trip makeTripWithNewName(String newName) {
    try {
        return new Trip(newName, this.gpsPoints);
    } catch (SpecialException exception) {
        // This code path will never be reached
        throw new RuntimeException(exception);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be part of your question?

Comment: @ChrisGong No, this is an answer that my friend gave to me on a chat just before I was thinking to post the question. Hence, I decided still to post the question and the answer as well.

Comment: instead of returning null i would rather recommend `throw new RuntimeException(exception);`

Comment: @911DidBush nice, didn't realise that this will compile

Answer (score 1):

`rename` sounds like a mutator method. So, traditionally you would like to make a change to the object itself instead of returning a new object. So, then `rename` would look like this:

```
public void rename(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

make sure that `name` is not `final`.

However, if you intend to return a copy of the object with only the name changed, your code looks good. If you don't want to handle the exception, you may consider making `SpecialException` an unchecked one by making it a subclass of `RuntimeException`.

Comment: You might want to review your answer - OP has changed some stuff and it first it looked to me like you are not answering the question at all.